# Как скрыть текст и убрать от него отступ?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, slider

Есть у меня слайдер с картинкой и текстом, который мне нужно скрыть или удалить. Делая это с помощью `font-size: 0;` у меня остается место под текст, т.к. контент получаю из php и хотя в коде это не видно, но у меня отступ внизу перед рамкой присутствует.

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему стилями или на худой конец скриптом, не правя html и php?

```css
.template-slider-body {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #979567;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.template-slider-body:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fdc447;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-slider-body ">
  <div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">
    <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.93 fullwidth mode -->
    <div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive">
      <img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
  " 
  Булочки в форме полумесяцев (нем. Kipferl) выпекались..."
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите решить проблему только силами CSS, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
.template-slider-body {
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
border: 2px solid #979567;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px transparent;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-bottom: 39px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.rev_slider_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Высота вашей картинки 100px (height="100"), поэтому задаем жесткую высоту для блока template-slider-body, далее скрываем все содержимое за пределами его видимой области (overflow: hidden;) и отодвигаем текст от элемента rev_slider_wrapper. В результате тект никуда не денется, но его не будет видно.

Хотя лучше, в ваше случае, как уже писали выше обернуть текст в 
    <span class="some-text"> 
и прописать стили конкретно для него.

Answer (score 4):

Поместите ваш текст в отдельный `<span>` и задайте ему `display:none;`

Comment: вы читать задание умеете? "не правя html и php?" ставлю минус на неумение читать